# Not able to use Microsoft translator after having clientID and client secret

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-translator

I have registered successfully on windows azure market place and I have a clientID and client secret, but I don't know how to use them in aspx page to translate a textbox text in desired language. I have this code but I don't know how to use it.
Should I write the below code in webservice??? If yes then on writing in webservice , it is reflecting error in `AdmAccessToken` and `AdmAccessToken`

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static AdmAccessToken GetAccessToken()
    {
        AdmAccessToken admToken;
        string headerValue;
        //Get Client Id and Client Secret from https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications/
        AdmAuthentication admAuth = new AdmAuthentication("clientid", "clientsecret");

        admToken = admAuth.GetAccessToken();
        // Create a header with the access_token property of the returned token
        headerValue = "Bearer" + " " + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(admToken.access_token);

        return admToken;
    }
```

This is the code on page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var languageFrom = "en";
        var languageTo = "de";
        var text = "Use pixels to express measurements for padding and margins.";
        function translate() {
            PageMethods.GetAccessToken(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);

        }
        function OnSucceeded(result, usercontext, methodName) {

            window.mycallback = function (response) {
                document.getElementById('<%= lblResult.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Translation for <br />source text: '" + text + "'<br /> from en to de <br /> " + response;
            }

            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?oncomplete=mycallback&appId=Bearer " + encodeURIComponent(result.access_token) + "&from=" + languageFrom + "&to=" + languageTo + "&text=" + text;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
        }
        function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
        <asp:Button ID="buttonTranslate" runat="server" Text="Translate" OnClientClick="translate();return false;" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help somebody so that I can translate my textbox text in any other language.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a Service Reference to the Microsoft Translator:

> **Adding the MS Translator reference**
>
> Right-click **References** -> **Add Service Reference**, type the http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/soap.svc into the **Address** field and click **Go** button. Name the service as *MsTranslatorService*.

Then, add the following code to the Defaults.aspx paying attention to **[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]** (which might coincide with the solution name by default, or you can see it in the "Inherits" Page attribute) and **[YOUR_APP_ID]**:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">

      void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         var ms = new [YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE].MsTranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient();
         ms.Open();
         var appId = "[YOUR_APP_ID]";
         var str = "Use pixels to express measurements for padding and margins.";
         var tar = ms.Translate(appId, str, "en", "de", null, "General");
         lblResult.Text = "Translation: " + tar; 
         ms.Close();
         ms = null;
      }

   </script>
```

Then, make sure your button code has the appropriate OnClick attribute:

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonTranslate" runat="server" Text="Translate" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" runat="server"/>
```

And then build the page and enjoy!

**EDIT:**
There is another way described at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted2.aspx, but I have not checked this. Note they are using http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate method, not the Ajax you mention.